# Google translate exclude words

Tags: google-translate, words

I have a Google translate on our site. I want to prevent some words and phrases from translation. Is it possible to create some list of NonTranslated words and word combinations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only possibility is to add `class="notranslate"` to the elements that shouldn´t be translated. To prevent the whole site from being translated, add `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">`